# Unresolved Proposal List

Tags: discussion

This is years out of date, but there is some history worth preserving, so I’m not going to delete it.

As a step toward ensuring that proposals don't languish in a limbo state where it's not clear whether the community wants to move forward with them or not, I'm compiling a list of proposals that have a concrete action we could take and that haven't been acted on and haven't been explicitly resolved.

I have not gone through all of the posts on meta yet. The proposals listed below are the highest voted discussions that I could find that looked like we would be able to categorize as "yes, do it", "no, don't do it", or "eh, who cares?".

Feel free to point out proposals I have missed. We have many important discussions that aren't on this list because they are not things we can mark as "done". **For tag cleaning proposals**, there are two questions on Meta that should be looked over:

[When to burninate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/239190/)

[How should we make requests to block tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/239189/)

If you want to make a new proposal for something concrete we can do, start the meta discussion (putting Proposal in the title helps it stand out) and I will add it to the list below.

This list is only numbered to make it easier to refer to a specific item on it and is not ordered by importance. I will be picking something off of this list to feature on meta for a week so that we can decide to take action or close it. I haven't decided how long it will be before I pick something; it will be at least a few days to give folks a chance to look at the list.

These proposals are just a starting point. We still need to go through the list and see if there are any that we can say "We agree and it's simple to do - let's just do it and cross it off." Others we will have to think about a bit more. For those I will probably write an "initiative" post that outlines a plan (or some different alternatives), get some feedback, and then do whatever that feedback seems to indicate, then mark the initiative post as "resolved" and add what we did to resolve it.

1. [Is This Tag Useful? Episode 1 - The Big Boss (grammar)](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2699/)
2. [Is This Tag Useful? Episode 2 -- The Twins (usage and meaning)](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2840/)
3. [Proposal: delete tags "meaning" and "word-meaning"](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2939/) (in progress)
4. <del>https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1230/ (should we merge word-difference with difference?)</del> Not enough interest
5. <del>https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2993/</del>
6. [Proposal: Blacklist [sentences]](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2994/) (tag destroyed, but not blacklisted. It will be if it pops up again)
7. <strike>https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/485/</strike>
8. [Pretentious writing tag](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1356/) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
9. [Which way should [speech] and [spoken-english] be merged?](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2829/)
10. [Proposal: tags for professional/specialty jargons](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3076/)
11. [Abolish off-topic tags [etymology] and [resources]](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1264/) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) ([resources](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resources) is gone and [etymology](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/etymology) is no longer strictly off-topic)
12. [Synonymize [opposite-word] to point to [antonyms]](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2761/) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
13. [Synonymize [negative] to point to [negation]](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2762/) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
14. [Should we prefer plural in tags?](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/68/) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
15. [Should we not use "verbs" instead of "verb"?](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3210/) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
16. [Custom off-topic reasons community wiki thread](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2412/)
17. [Let's rewrite the "Proofreading" close reason](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2547/)

Comment: Whew!  That's quite a bit.  Thanks for putting the list together. I'll probably handle #15 soon.  Enough time has passed with no objections, I think.   (It looks like #15 subsumes #14.)

Comment: @snailplane There are a couple that are related - I tried to group them but this is just a quick and dirty first pass. I promised I'd have this done today and I've got errands to run this afternoon :)

Comment: We can first delete the tags whose fate has been decided and then retag their questions, or just start retagging. The latter doesn't require mods doing anything but it can get messy. I can organize a retagging chat event. So, what's it going to be?

Comment: @Rubisco I understand that you're anxious to get going, but this isn't the great retagging part 2 :) We're going to take one proposal at a time, and figure out how to close it. Then we'll cross it off the list and pick the next one.

Comment: Well, how are we going to deal with 1?

Comment: @Rubisco We will figure it out when we decide to work on it - I don't think we should take on the big boss until we've leveled up a little bit and done the obligatory "kill the rats in the basement" quest.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is very out of date and further interaction with it would probably be better as a new post.